# Android Kotlin how do I add JSON data into spinner/drop down?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, spinner, dropdown

I am trying to put JSON data into a spinner for example the sizes of the clothing into a drop down menu

```
  val product_sizes = productfeed.variants.distinctBy { it.option_values[0].name }.forEach{Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${it.option_values[0].name}")}
```

This is grabbing the sizes from JSON data with the output on Logcat:

> TESTING:: SMALL
> TESTING:: MEDIUM
> TESTING:: LARGE
> TESTING:: 1 XL
> TESTING:: 2 XL
> TESTING:: 3 XL

But i am having trouble putting it into a spinner

```
  if (spinner_product != null) {
        val adapter =
            ArrayAdapter(this@ProductActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                **sizes**)
        spinner_product.adapter = adapter

        //  Log.d("SPINNER", "this is ${spinner_product.display.state}")

        spinner_product.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ProductActivity,
                        " " + "" + productfeed.variants[position].option_values[0].name,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    size_text.text = sizes[position]

                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }
            }
```

Comment: Whats the trouble?

Comment: Whenever I put it into a spinner it only displays as "kotlin.unit" i dont know how to put that JSON data in a spinner

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `ArrayAdapter` is using a custom class of whatever `productfeed.variants` is. So in order for it to display in your spinner correctly you could simply override the `toString()` method on your `productfeed.variants` class i.e.:

```
data class YourClassName(
    val name: String
) {
     override fun toString(): String = name
}
```

[ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

> By default, the array adapter creates a view by calling
> Object#toString() on each data object in the collection you provide,
> and places the result in a TextView.

Alternatively you may create a custom `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView()` and set the view to what you want;

```
val adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<YourClass>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, variants) {
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
            val text1 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView    
            text1.setText(variants[position].name) 
            return view
        }
    }
```